# requests.get not getting correct information

Tags: python

I want to get several "pages" of a website and for some reason the correct url does not give the expected result.

I looked at the url that should be used and it works just fine and tried to use some variable changing.

```
for i in range(1,100):
    MLinks.append("https://#p" + str(i))

for i in range(1,100):
    x = i-1
    MainR = requests.get(MLinks[x])

    SMHTree = html.fromstring(MainR.content)
    MainData = SMHTree.xpath('//@*')
    j=0
    while j <len(MainData):
        if 'somthing' in MainData[j] :
            PLinks.append(MainData[j]) #Links of products
        j=j+1
```

I am expecting to get every page but when I am reading the contents I always get the contents of the first page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the URLs you are requesting look like this:

```
https://somehost.com/products/#p1
https://somehost.com/products/#p2
https://somehost.com/products/#p3
...
```

That is, the second line of you code would actually be

```
MLinks.append("https://somehost.com/products/#p" + str(i))
```

When doing the request, the server never sees the part after the # (this part is called an anchor). So the server just receives 100 requests for "https://somehost.com/products/", which all give the same results. See this website explaining it further: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL.

Anchors are sometimes used by client-side JavaScript to load pages dynamically. What this means is that if you open "https://somehost.com/products/" and navigate to "https://somehost.com/products/#p5", the client-side JavaScript will notice it and (usually) issue a request to some other URL to load the products on page 5. This other URL will not be "https://somehost.com/products/#5"! To find out what this URL is, open the developer tools of your browser and see what network requests are made when you navigate to a different product page.